# Add sale count next to star rating in woocommerce single product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to add order, sale count next to star rating at single product page, my store is built with WordPress and Woocommerce, I have tried a code but it adds this function before add to cart button/form.

Website URL for reference: https://techcart.pk

and image

[image]

**Code:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'product_sold_count', 10 );
  function product_sold_count() {
   global $product;
   $units_sold = $product->get_total_sales();
   if ( $units_sold ) echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
```

I will appreciate if anyone helps me in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

For **single product** page, I tested it with the themes: ShoppingCart and Storefront and it works fine  :

in `function.php`:

```
function shoppingcart_setup(){

  add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', function(){
    
     global $product;
     $units_sold = $product->get_total_sales();
     if ( $units_sold ) return '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';             
        
  }, 10, 2);
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'shoppingcart_setup' );
```

**Note:** If you checked: Manage Stock, this code does not work